# Is it possible to Sort Arrays with custom objects containing String elements localized AND with correct Numbers in Cocoa Touch?

Tags: cocoa, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

Assumed having the class Account with Name and accountNo both as NSStrings. I want to sort an Array of Accounts either by name or by accountNo. The sort should be done localized.

If I use NSSortDescriptors as described in the Guides I have the option to pass *localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:* to the Array, but the numbers are not sorted correctly (100 is sorted before 99). I have not found a way to trigger the option *NSNumericSearch* for the search.
This means I have to use *sortedArrayUsingFunctions* with a function in every class along the chain. It allows me to sort with correct numerical values but this is not localized and very functional.

If you have answers to both questions (SortDescriptors with Numerically correct sort or sortFunctions with localized and numeric correct sort) please provide me both

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a different `NSSortDescriptor` for each property by which you wish to sort.  Each sort descriptor can use a different comparison selector.  Your strings can use your `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:` method, and your numbers can use a custom sort selector, something like `compareNumeric:`.

Then you can just add a category to `NSString` that defines a method called `compareNumeric:` that does this:

```
- (NSComparisonResult) compareNumeric:(id)other {
  return [self compare:other options:NSNumericSearch];
}
```

Comment: Hi Dave,

sorry for the late answer, I stumbled over this problem now for the second time, I have not really solved it the last time - I just have decided to use only NSNumericSearch because the visibility is higher.
Actually your example is not fully matching the requirements: I have strings with both numbers and chars like "123 Max" and "4 Steve". Using the localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare would sort them Max first and Steve second. When using functions the search is correct but not localized.
I haven't found a solution yet. But as soon as I have one, I will provide it.

Thanks for the answer